# why does my sublime now show these black empty folders

Tags: themes, updates, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

since updating sublime, the editor now displays two folders next to each folder.[image: notice black outlined folders next to blue ones]

I am using a customized version of the Flatland theme.

Comment: Which OS are you using and how do you open sublime ? (command-line/shortcut etc)

Answer (score 1):

The latest ST3 update added new folder and file type icons. You will either have to switch to a different theme that supports these new icons or [update your customized Flatland theme to disable them](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/flatland/commit/af6dedbac1e446f791adc759d04ff52d0f47859e).